# Increase timeout of GWT Front-End while invoking AsyncCallback

Tags: java, gwt, timeout, asynccallback

I have a GWT based UI and it connects to a Web Service (3rd Party) to submit a few requests. When the request is big (like really really big), the application used to timeout since the 3rd party total execution time of the request was 72 seconds while our connection timeout was set to 60 seconds, so before even the response comes from 3rd Party, out application would timeout. So I increased the **ServiceClient**  timeout to **200 seconds** from **60 seconds**. The request is submitted using **AsynCallback**. This worked great in my local IBM WebSphere server (DEV Environment).

The problem is, when I try to submit the request in Test Environment, the UI times out in **60 seconds** and user is shown internal server error but in the background, the **AsynCallBack** still executes and it also performs the post submission activity once the response is received (after **72 seconds**).

**How can I put a hold to the UI timeout until the AsynCallback returns a response (200 sec) ?**

I couldn't find any timeout settings set for the GWT UI.

Comment: What is ServiceClient? And how and where do you set the timeout?

Comment: I'm using Axis2 Service Client. I'm setting the timeout at this:-
stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(200000);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was resolved by changing the **read/write timeout** value in Web Server **Plug-in Properties** of associated cluster of WebSphere.

Answer (score 0):

The callback timeout is most likely handled by the server. You would need to modify the server's connector to extend the timeout there.

If you are using tomcat your problem is the default timeout of the connector is 60 seconds. You can modify this with the connectionTimeout option.

[Tomcat configurations](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

If you are running long running calls to the server. You may want to look into doing something with a comet/push event to notify the client when the job is done. I have used a couple of processes for this in the past. [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) is an excellent library that support websockets and http push. I have also used a queue with websockets and STOMP to push events to web clients. Many times this is the right way to go if you are going to use this in production. This problem will definitely arise if you ever put it behind a proxy or a load balancer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not possible to implement an external library at this moment. I'm using IBM WebSphere.  And we're actually behind a proxy/load balancer. Could you explain how that can be a problem. Also, any WebSphere settings that can be changed to avoid this ?

Comment: It may not be WebSphere that is causing the problem. It is very likely that the problem is with the proxy/load balancer that is killing your connection. The reason that proxy/load balancers will close a connection after a number of seconds is to free up resources. This is so that you cannot exhaust the number of connections and or memory of the load balancer/proxy. This is why a lb closes connections so that other clients can still access resources. If your request is going to take longer than 40 seconds you need to use an async push service to alert the client that the long running process

Comment: has completed. You may also be able to get away with this if you are using websockets rather than the normal http transport.